# getting text between xmlnodes

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, vb.net

How can we get the text between XML nodes

```
<company>
<data id="14" />{<data id="15" />DOCUMENT<data id="23" />pet<data id="24" />DOCUMENT<data id="25" />
</company>
```

I need data between id 23 and 25 (i.e pet DOCUMENT)

I have loaded this xml in xmldoc

Please suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(@"<company>...</company");

string result = string.Join(" ",
    doc.Root
       .Nodes()
       .SkipWhile(n => n.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Element ||
                       (int)((XElement)n).Attribute("id") != 23)
       .TakeWhile(n => n.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Element ||
                       (int)((XElement)n).Attribute("id") != 25)
       .OfType<XText>());

// result == "pet DOCUMENT"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim tDoc as XmlDocument = new XmlDocument
Dim tNodes As XmlNodeList = Nothing

tDoc.Load(path_to_xml_file)   ' Or .LoadXml(xml_string)
tNodes = tDoc.SelectNodes("//data")

For Each tNode As XmlNode In tNodes
  Select Case tNode.Attributes("id").value
    Case 23, 24, 25
      ' Do your processing here
  End Select
Next
```

**EDIT**
I misread the XML above.  Anyhow...  I don't know about getting the text between specific node IDs.. but you can get all the text with `tDoc.SelectSingleNode("//company").InnerText`

Comment: I need text between theses nodes. how Can I get the text ?

Answer (score 0):

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(@"<company>...</company");

string result = string.Join(" ",
    doc.Root
       .Nodes()
       .SkipWhile(n => n.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Element ||
                       (int)((XElement)n).Attribute("id") != 23)
       .TakeWhile(n => n.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Element ||
                       (int)((XElement)n).Attribute("id") != 25)
       .OfType<XText>());
```